# Use/add shell script to msysgit

Tags: git, sh, msysgit

I'm using msysgit on Windows and wrote a simple shell script that I would like to use. I added the folder that the .sh file is in to the PATH variable of my Windows computer but when I want to use my script I have to type rd.sh instead of just plain rd.

How do I use this by just referring to its name rd and not the full file name with the .sh file extension (rd.sh)?

Comment: @shellter: msysgit provides a Unix-like bash shell environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell provided with msysgit is bash, which runs in an emulated Unix-like environment.

If you're running the script from the bash shell, you need to type the name of the script, which as far as the Unix-like environment is concerned is `rd.sh`.  The `.sh` has no particular meaning in a Unix environment; it's just the last three characters of the file name.  The first line of the script should be `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`; this is known as a ["shebang"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

On the other hand, if you want to run it from Windows (say, from a `cmd.exe` command prompt), then the `.sh` extension is used by Windows to determine how to execute it, and you can invoke it as `rd` if (a) it's in a directory in your `%PATH%`, and (b) Windows is configured (in Folder Options and/or by setting `%PATHEXT%`) to use `sh` or `bash` to launch `.sh` files.

If you want to be able to run the same script from either environment, you can create a symbolic link that will be recognized in the emulated Unix-like environment.  For example, if `rd.sh` is in `$HOME/bin`, then this:

```
ln -s $HOME/bin/rd.sh $HOME/bin/rd
```

will create the appropriate symlink.  (You could make `rd` a copy of `rd.sh`, but then changes to one won't apply to the other.)

If you only need to run it from bash, just call it `rd` rather than `rd.sh`; as I mentioned, as far as bash is concerned the `.sh` extension is just part of the name and has no particular significance.  It's the `#!` line, not the `.sh` extension, that tells bash how to execute the script.

(Well, strictly speaking it's not bash that handles the `#!`.  On actual Unix or Linux systems, it's handled by the kernel; I'm not sure what the exact mechanism is under msysgit.)

Comment: I've search far too long for this. Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would do this by adding the extension `.sh` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable.  `PATHEXT` is a semicolon separated list of extensions to treat as executable.

However, since windows doesn't have built in support for shell scripts (other than batch files and the like obviously) I'm not 100% sure if this will work.